# A remarkable feature of the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: derivatives

While doing some calculus problems I came across the remarkable discovery that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ actually equals its own derivative at the $x$ value of $-\frac {1}{\phi}$ ($\approx -0.618033$, $\phi$ being the golden ratio, approx. $1.618033$).

This led me to ask, why? I tried setting the two equations equal to each other, and $-1/\phi$ does indeed come out as a solution of the quadratic $\frac {1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, but what does the square root of $5$ have to do with the golden ratio? And why?

Just for the record, the derivative of f(x) is $\frac {-x}{1-x^2}$
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mis ordered the question: the "two equations" I mentioned are f(x) and f'(x).

Comment: Your function  satisfies $f’f+x=0$, so if $f’=f$ we have $f^2+x=0$ or $1-x^2+x=0$. This is precisely the equation for the golden ratio $\phi$ and it’s negative inverse $-\frac{1}{\phi}$. Since $f$ has a domain of $x \leq 1$ and is positive , we need to disregard the golden ratio. Hence the negative inverse is the solution to $f=f’$. As for why it satisfies $-\frac{1}{\phi}$ satisfies these equations, why not?

Answer (score 4):

The golden ratio is given by $1:\phi = \phi:(1-\phi)$, which produces the quadratic equation  $1-\phi=\phi^2$, i.e., $\phi$ is a solution of $x^2+x-1=0$. The solutions are $\frac{-1\pm\color{red}{\sqrt 5} }{2}$.